# ES6 Module short circuiting

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ecmascript-6

You can prevent loading already loaded dependencies using Browserify/Require/etc

```
var React = React || require('react');
```

**Is this possible with ES6 Modules?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible with ES6 Modules?

If you ask whether it is possible to declare a dependency conditionally, the answer is no. However, you might be able to use [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) to load the module on demand.

> You can always do this, but it's not as clean looking...

No you cannot. `import` and `export` declarations cannot be nested. They have to appear at the top level.

> Some libraries out there (I'm looking at you, React) really don't like being loaded twice

Modules are only evaluated *once*, no matter how often they are imported. If you have problems with React then likely because you are loading two different versions / copies. The solution to this problem is to ensure to only load a single copy.

Answer (score -1):

ES6 Modules are singletons, so, if a module is imported multiple times only a single instance of it exists - *source - **the internet***

Comment: Can you share a link to that internet? :-)